# out of multiple occurrences of item, remove only the second one

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

My array looks like this:

```
{"numb":1, "idSpec":55,}
{"numb":2, "idSpec":42,}
{"numb":3, "idSpec":96,}
{"numb":4, "idSpec":96,}
{"numb":5, "idSpec":96,}
{"numb":6, "idSpec":96,}
```

You can see that `idSpec: 96` has multiple occurrences in my object.

This is my desired output

```
{"numb":1, "idSpec":55,}
{"numb":2, "idSpec":42,}
{"numb":3, "idSpec":96,}
{"numb":5, "idSpec":96,}
{"numb":6, "idSpec":96,}
```

How can I only remove `idSpec`'s **second** occurrence?

Comment: May be you can filter your array with field `numb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is iterate over your array, keep track of the already seen specIds and remove the first, second occurency. This could look smh like this:

```
const seenIds = [];
const removedIds = []; 

array = array.filter(item => {
 // We haven't seen the id yet. add it to the seenIds and return the element
 if (!seenIds.includes(item.specId)) {
   seenIds.push(item.specId)
   return true
 }

 // We have seen the element but havent removed it yet (second occurency) remove the element
 if(!removedIds.includes(item.specId)) {
  removedIds.push(item.specId)
  return false
 }

 // We have seen the Element but its at least the third occurency.
 return true
})
```

(In this szenario we are looping over array just once so its O(n) Iterations.)

Comment: should be `idSpec` rather than `specId`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
const data = [{ numb: 1, idSpec: 55 }, { numb: 2, idSpec: 42 }, { numb: 3, idSpec: 96 }, { numb: 4, idSpec: 96 }, { numb: 5, idSpec: 96 }, { numb: 6, idSpec: 96 }];

const removeSecond = (items) => {
   const idSpecMap = {};
   return items
       .map((item) => {
           idSpecMap[item.idSpec] = (idSpecMap[item.idSpec] || 0) + 1;
           return {
               ...item,
               count: idSpecMap[item.idSpec],
           };
       })
       .filter((item) => item.count !== 2)
       .map(({ count, ...rest }) => rest);
};

console.log(removeSecond(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below I've composed a function which will help you filter the `n`th occurrence of something in an array. You can use it on the data in your example, or with any other type of array data that you need to get a filtered version of based on similar criteria (position of occurrence). The code includes comments to explain how it works and tests to prove its effectiveness.

> The English description of the logic is that you just use a `Map` to keep a running count of each occurrence of the value you're interested in comparing (which is determined by a selector function), and filter out the occurrence counts which match the target value:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=51&ssc=1&pln=54&pc=61#code/PQKhCgAIUglBTALgVwE4DsDOkCGkBmAlgDaLyrwAmuqqOAngDSTwAeAxscpYegOaREAC3iR0wyAHt27NBXTtRk-LkgA3HF1GZ4xeOzKUoMfKkkBbFjnZCWe8-HHHjkAAIAHHHUte69SACq6ESk5FQ0fi4eXjiW6JAA6kKENlIyco6KgpIsHFyUogAURKiYiGmytJmihNgAjACUUZ7ekDp6BpKokABiyAqIhJLx+F1tuvqD-ARmlvDWQi6+DHbwDuKCIuqayKKIOewWLfBRFCgY2D0kZBTUy-TGwOD4-QZDI9fkAHLCAPLpVQUogAPAAVZgANQAfIUoBEGAAuSAUHCUYbEfyggDaAF1GHD4gBeSAABnxkHGHX2qCRhQ0WiRoIakEJUMgEJZkDpO3gzNZ2y0uGw-QA1uhJAB3eI4bAQ-ENRm4yAAbzhhyw5UO-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-sQzB+ZMVAvS6kh6KWz58IUADk8DfQicPA99WZlReRpdHeD4Ijtua4ADmhiYd7o-EI-xtdUF3oDRzAhXdbIPU9+jgxquT+VQJN0XlKmyW55m5YZSU2QL6WOSLBUs0VuWla9gPc5+v6A796D-ftxAxSDBhc2zwFQzD8OIwryOowr6O7UTxCqaTR7k5TGRAoUWJwzgKOQHD1ru3D7De27zCe37Qd4o1evlNrhg23Rrve17Ae+wH-se27csE8bmhR0r32q+rgMpRHVCqXrkPwNDkiwwj32qabLBV1mQA)

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Returns a filtered array, excluding the nth occurrence of a value selected
 * from each element
 *
 * @param array - Unfiltered array
 * @param n - Which occurrence to exclude (first occurrence is 1)
 * @param selector - Function for selecting from each
 * array element the value to compare
 * @returns Filtered array
 */
function filterNthOccurrence (
  array,
  n = 0,
  selector = (value) => value,
) {
  const counts = new Map();
  const filtered = [];

  for (const element of array) {
    const value = selector(element);
    const count = (counts.get(value) ?? 0) + 1;
    counts.set(value, count);
    if (count !== n) filtered.push(element);
  }

  return filtered;
}

// Used in the tests below
function areEqualJson (a,  b) {
  return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
}

const input = [
  {numb: 1, idSpec: 55},
  {numb: 2, idSpec: 42},
  {numb: 3, idSpec: 96},
  {numb: 4, idSpec: 96},
  {numb: 5, idSpec: 96},
  {numb: 6, idSpec: 96},
];

const expected = [
  {numb: 1, idSpec: 55},
  {numb: 2, idSpec: 42},
  {numb: 3, idSpec: 96},
  {numb: 5, idSpec: 96},
  {numb: 6, idSpec: 96},
];

//                                        filter the 2nd occurrence
//                                        ^  select the "idSpec" prop for comparison
//                                        ^  ^
const actual = filterNthOccurrence(input, 2, o => o.idSpec);
const equal = areEqualJson(actual, expected);
console.log('equal:', equal);


// More tests:
const actual2 = filterNthOccurrence(input, 1, o => o.idSpec);
const expected2 = [
  {numb: 4, idSpec: 96},
  {numb: 5, idSpec: 96},
  {numb: 6, idSpec: 96},
];
const equal2 = areEqualJson(actual2, expected2);
console.log('equal2:', equal2);

const actual3 = filterNthOccurrence(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'], 2);
const expected3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'];
const equal3 = areEqualJson(actual3, expected3);
console.log('equal3:', equal3);
```